# MPI Pobe and Get_count in send/recv communication

Tags: c, mpi

I wrote a parallel program based on master slave paradigm, but when I use probe and get gout to get the length of the message it always says that it is 0 but that's not true

```
if(!rank){
    for (int i = 1; i < num_procs; ++i) {

            /* receive chunk dimension */
            MPI_Recv(&recv_size, 1, MPI_INT, i, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

            /* read from file, here the recv_size is 10000 but in file there are
             just 997 point to read, so the value of recv_size become 997, this 
             is what the function readPoint() does  */

            err = readPoint(dataset, points, &recv_size, o_size);
            if(err) {
                MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MEM_ALLOC_ERROR);
                exit(MEM_ALLOC_ERROR);
            }
            printf("recv_size %d\n", recv_size); /* this print 997 */

            /* send it to slave */

            MPI_Send(points, recv_size, Point_type, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }


        /* [... rest of the master logic ...] */
}
else{
       while (1){
      
            chunk_size = computeAvaiableMemory();
            points = (Point *) realloc(points, chunk_size * sizeof(Point));
            if(!points){
                MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MEM_ALLOC_ERROR);
                exit(MEM_ALLOC_ERROR);
            }

            /* Send chunk dimension */

            MPI_Send(&chunk_size, 1, MPI_INT, ROOT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            /* receive its part of point to process */

            MPI_Probe(ROOT, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status2);
            MPI_Get_count(&status2, Point_type, &chunk_size);
            printf("chunk size %d\n", chunk_size); /* this is printing 0 */
            if(chunk_size == 0) break;

            MPI_Recv(points, chunk_size, Point_type, ROOT, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status2);
            
            /* [... rest of the slave logic ...]*/
       
        }
```

I expect that the slave, when calling printf, will print 977. I don't understand why it get 0 length from the function get count

Edit: I run the program with 2 processes

Comment: Is there something missing on that first `if{` line?

Comment: yes, sorry i'm editing. It was an error in copy and past

Comment: How many processes are you running? Are you sure it sends 997 to each worker process? (Note the word I just used. It's preferable that the one you used.)

Comment: Just 2 processes, 1 worker process and 1 slave process, so I'm sure of what should happen

Comment: Please post a [mcve] since the root cause might not be in the snippet you posted

Comment: You can find the complete code here https://github.com/simonerusso97/bfr-clustering-parallelized/blob/develop/main.c but I'm sure there are no error that can cause this problem before

Comment: If you are sure there are no errors before, then it will be trivial so trim your code down to a [mcve] so you do not even need to share a link to the full code.

Comment: The complete code is extremely messy. But even even from your example I can say that because you have `if(chunk_size == 0) break;` between `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` you will have unmatched communication.

And from your code on github I can see that you have it in many places. So the question, are you sure that the `MPI_Probe` is checking the appropriate `MPI_Send`?